# What's the most efficient way to fit a surface to three or more points?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

Say I have a function of the form $s=b-mp+at$, where $p$ and $t$ are the independent variables, and I have 3 or more points of the form $(p,t,s)$.  I want to find the best values for $b$, $m$, and $a$ to give me the best fit. Is there an analogue of linear regression for this situation?

Comment: Shouldn't the points have three coordinates?

Comment: For each of your $(x,y)$ points, you need the corresponding value of $s$.  And if you have three of them, you will not get the "best" fit, you will get the only fit.

Comment: Oops yeah. I will fix the question. Thanks!

Comment: Despite the habit of naming coordinates $(x, y, z)$, it's really best to be consistent with your notation.  According to the first sentence, your points are of the form $(p, t, s)$.

Comment: @KorganRivera Again - unless your samples are colinear, there is exactly one plane such that all three points are on it. There is no regression going on.

Comment: They're not colinear. So how do I figure out the surface without regression?

Comment: I agree with AlexR. This looks more like linear algebra, where one constructs a plane in terms of the coordinates of three of its points.

Comment: My linear algebra is weak. If someone can post a solution, that would be useful.

Comment: I suppose the reason I'm  looking for a regression solution, is that later I may be working with more than 3 points. Ideally, if someone can provide both a linear algebra solution for 3 points and a regression solution for other cases, that would be great.

Comment: Points are $(x1,y1,z1), (x2,y2,z2), (x3,y3,z3)$. Choose one point $P$, say the first. Take differences between 2 and 1: $V= (x2-x1,y2-y1,z2-z1)$ and between 3 and 1: $W = (x3-x1,y3-y1,z3-z1)$. Then the expression for the plane through the three points is: $R = P + m*V + n*W$ where $m$ and $n$ are real variables.

Comment: I've  updated the question to reflect that regression is indeed the required method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some matrix algebra equations you can try.  I'm suggesting this approach because you mentioned that there may be future cases where you have more than three points to work with and in such cases the linear regression solution is what you want.

Starting with your equation for $s$, define the following quantities:

$$\underline s = \begin{bmatrix}
s_1\\
s_2\\
s_3
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$X = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \ \ p_1 \ \ t_1\\
1 \ \ p_2 \ \ t_2\\
1 \ \ p_3 \ \ t_3\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\underline\beta = \begin{bmatrix}
b\\
m\\
a
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then per your equation $\underline s = X \ \underline\beta$.  In your case you have three data points and 3 unknowns.  If $X$ is full column rank (its determinant is not zero, points are not colinear) and since $X$ is square, multiplication of both sides of the equation for $ \underline s$ by $X^{-1}$ gives $\underline\beta = X^{-1} \underline s$.

If you have more than three data points (more than 3 rows of the $s$ vector and the X matrix) the following equation will do the trick:
$$\underline\beta = (X'X)^{-1}X' \underline s$$ again as long as $X$ is full column rank, or equivalently, as long as $det(X'X) \neq 0$.  In this case the equation gives the least squares estimate for $\underline \beta$.

The second equation will work as well for the case of only 3 points, which means you can solve your initial problem with a standard regression package.  In this case you have a saturated model which has no degrees of freedom left over to estimate an error term, but with three points and three parameters to estimate you'll have a perfect fit, as has been pointed out in the comments.  I hope this helps.

Comment: You are awesome.  Thank you!  I just finished coding a set of basic linear algebra functions, I tried out your formula and, so far, everything is working perfectly!  Thanks!